# Return array from function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

--Solved by Elliot B. Thanks!
May also take into account the other modifications.

Here is the result. Thanks, everyone, for the speedy answers! http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18785762/Rust/index.html

I'm writing a game in javascript, and I want to keep the files for matching block IDs to files in a seperate .js file from the map compiler, so that I can edit things easily. However, the IDs are stored in an array, and I can't seem to get it to use the return function properly. Any help?

drawmap.js:

```
function drawmap() {
    
    var images = BlockID();
    
    var level = [
    "ssssssssssssssssssssss",
    "sgggggggggCCCCCdddddss",
    "ssssssssss     sssssss"
    ];

    var top = 100;
    var left = 100;
    var mytop = top;
    var myleft = left;
    for (y=0; y<level.length; ++y) {
        var row = level[y];
        for (x=0; x < row.length; ++x) {
            var c = row.charAt(x);
            if(c != ' ') {
                img_create(images[c], mytop, myleft);
            }
            mytop += 13;
            myleft += 27;
        }
        mytop = top + (y+1)*13;
        myleft = left - (y+1)*27;
    }
}
```

mapread.js:

```
function BlockID() {
    var IDs = new Array();
        images['s'] = "Images/Block_01.png";
        images['g'] = "Images/Block_02.png";
        images['C'] = "Images/Block_03.png";
        images['d'] = "Images/Block_04.png";
    return IDs;
}
```

Comment: So what is not working properly.  Are you getting errors in console log?

Comment: change `images` to `IDs` and it will work…

Comment: Instead of "new Array()" or "new Object()", I would use "[ ]" or "{ }" respectively.

Comment: I agree @ianpgall -hence my post :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

At a minimum, change this:

```
function BlockID() {
    var IDs = new Array();
        images['s'] = "Images/Block_01.png";
        images['g'] = "Images/Block_02.png";
        images['C'] = "Images/Block_03.png";
        images['d'] = "Images/Block_04.png";
    return IDs;
}
```

To this:

```
function BlockID() {
    var IDs = new Object();
        IDs['s'] = "Images/Block_01.png";
        IDs['g'] = "Images/Block_02.png";
        IDs['C'] = "Images/Block_03.png";
        IDs['d'] = "Images/Block_04.png";
    return IDs;
}
```

There are a couple fixes to point out. **First**, `images` is not defined in your original function, so assigning property values to it will throw an error. We correct that by changing `images` to `IDs`. **Second**, you want to return an `Object`, not an `Array`. An object can be assigned property values akin to an associative array or hash -- an array cannot. So we change the declaration of `var IDs = new Array();` to `var IDs = new Object();`.

After those changes your code will run fine, but it can be **simplified further**. You can use shorthand notation (i.e., object literal property value shorthand) to create the object and return it immediately:

```
function BlockID() {
    return {
            "s":"Images/Block_01.png"
            ,"g":"Images/Block_02.png"
            ,"C":"Images/Block_03.png"
            ,"d":"Images/Block_04.png"
    };
}
```

Comment: One should use an object here, not an array.

Comment: Thank you! It works now. I'll accept the answer when the 15-minute cooldown is over.

Comment: @pimvdb is right. @AidanEdwards If you're not using integers for indices, `Array()` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Aidan Edwards: Arrays are basically lists with indices (access them with `[0]` etc). Objects are generic key/value pairs, which is what you're using.

Answer (score 14):

Your `BlockID` function uses the undefined variable `images`, which will lead to an error. Also, you should not use an `Array` here - JavaScripts key-value-maps are plain objects:

```
function BlockID() {
    return {
        "s": "Images/Block_01.png",
        "g": "Images/Block_02.png",
        "C": "Images/Block_03.png",
        "d": "Images/Block_04.png"
    };
}
```

Answer (score 8):

neater:

```
function BlockID() {
  return {
    "s":"Images/Block_01.png",
    "g":"Images/Block_02.png",
    "C":"Images/Block_03.png",
    "d":"Images/Block_04.png"
   }
}
```

or just

```
var images = {
  "s":"Images/Block_01.png",
  "g":"Images/Block_02.png",
  "C":"Images/Block_03.png",
  "d":"Images/Block_04.png"
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the IDs in a separate file, I'll probable use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration that in JavaScript Array is object too this can be written as:

```
function BlockID() {
    return new Array(
        "Images/Block_01.png", 
        "Images/Block_02.png", 
        "Images/Block_03.png", 
        "Images/Block_04.png" 
       );
    }
```

This code will display content of array in browser's window

```
window.onload=function(){
var s="";
var ar = BlockID(); //function return array
for(el in ar){
    s+=ar[el]+"</br>";
}
document.body.innerHTML=s; 
};
```