# Search function return multiple results

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to make a search function that searches an array for a string and returns the index of the location in the array for which it matches the string.

Ex:

```
Array: [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,6,5,2]
Search input: 3
Output: 
2
6

Search input: 2
Output:
1
5
10
```

Currently i have it outputting only 1 value by using

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=
```

But I want it to return multiple results

Comment: Can you add more information about what you are trying to do? It's not clear how the example you gave relates to the javascript fragment you provided. Can you provide some of the surrounding code that would utilize the requested search function?

Comment: Please provide code for what you're trying to do and what you've tried.. looks like you just stopped typing in the middle of a sentence and posted

Comment: This is what I have right now: http://i.imgur.com/2SrWrkr.png. After pressing search, the result/results will show up on the right hand side, under Results.

Answer (score 2):

If you write your own function, you should be able to [return an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059478/return-array-from-function) of indices:

```
function indicesOf(input, value) {
    var indices = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] == value)
            indices.push(i);
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Then you can combine the array values and put them into the result location, as suggested by @AnthonyGrist:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = indicesOf(input, value).join(', ');
```

Comment: Thank you. THe problem is that I'm trying to return the values inside a specific cell in a table, which was why I tried to use the getElementByID

Comment: If you have access to an array of values, you should be able to pass that arry to the function I wrote: indicesOf(document.getElementByID("result")... but I can't tell what arguments to use because I don't have enough information about your situation.

Comment: @Nonono If you write a function that returns an array, you can use the `join` function to convert it to a nicely formed string with your results, something like: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = indicesOf(input, value).join(', ');`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - thanks! With your example, I finally understand the OP's javascript fragment!

Comment: This is what I have right now: i.imgur.com/2SrWrkr.png. After pressing search, the result/results will show up on the right hand side, under Results. Do you think that'll work @AnthonyGrist ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're after, but if you want to return all objects with a given selector from DOM (as opposed to acting on and returning filtered javascript array) then you could use `document.querySelectorAll(<your_selector_here>)` - [more information at MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,1,6,5,2];
arr.map(function(x, i){
   return x == 3 ? i : null;
}).filter(Number); // get indexes
```

The above maps and filters out the index. Then it is simply a matter of joining it

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= arr.join("<br />");
```